# Is it possible to use some sort of tool for making it easier to have touchscreen feature for OneNote in a laptop?

Tags: touchscreen

I want to use touch feature for writing handwritten notes on OneNote in a laptop (which is not touchscreen), can it be made possible ?

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: So.... you want a program to use your non-touchscreen computer...... as a touchscreen?

Comment: Yeah this Sir .

Comment: It's simply not possible at all. If your computer hasn't the physical capability to read touch input, no program will ever be able to make it work like a touchscreen. You need additional hardware, no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device doesn't support touch input, then no piece of software will ever convert it to a touchscreen.

The hardware is physically not capable of receiving such input, so the computer won't be able to know that you're using the "touchscreen". Software can only be made to process data the computer already has or is able to capture though its attached devices.

No software will create such capability, if the device doesn't support it. First you need to consider a hardware upgrade to enable such thing, then we can think about some program for using that.

Answer (score 0):

If you laptop doesn't have touchscreen you need to add a touchscreen hardware: [AirBar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N3MHMSF)

Comment: Is AirBar  available for all different laptops? (Leaving Apples ones as i am not buying for now that)

Comment: @Alejandro this is an hardware recommendation, that's right. This because in your previous comment to the post you said that is impossible to have a software doing that, that's why you need hardware

Comment: @Orion_Pax apparently there is one compatible only with MacbookAir: https://www.amazon.com/AirBar-Neonode-Add-Touchscreen-MacBook-Notebooks/dp/B072PCZZJZ

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani Given that the question is posted on Software Recommendations, it's clear to me that the OP want a program, not an extra gadget. Should he want to consider that option, the question can be posted on [Hardware Recomendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Wooooo... @Alejandro, I didn't know that community. Amazing! Thank you so much, I'm going to join them. Thanks